# ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.nvidia-smi-test: 'runtime'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cuda, nvidia, nvidia-docker

this is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
 nvidia-smi-test:
  runtime: nvidia
  image: nvidia/cuda:9.0-base
  environment:
      - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
```

when I run `docker-compose up` it will appear:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.nvidia-smi-test: 'runtime'
```

but if I don't use docker-compose just use command `docker run --runtime=nvidia nvidia/cuda:9.0-base  nvidia-smi`
**there is no error** ，
I don't know exactly what went wrong。Below is version of docker and docker-compose:

```
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
docker-compose version 1.17.0, build ac53b73
```

I would be very grateful if everyone could make some comments！

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem, this is because the docker-compose version is not right, **Docker Compose must be version 1.19.0 or higher.**

I just uninstall the docker-compose (version 1.17.0) and install docker-compose(version 1.21.2) everything goes well!